# Am I missing something when using MassTransit and AmazonSQS in a large project?

Tags: .net-core, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, masstransit

I'm using MassTransit in a project with AmazonSQS and since I updated the packages to the latest version 7.3 I'm getting this exception

```
     ---> Amazon.SimpleNotificationService.AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceException: Rate exceeded
 ---> Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException: Exception of type 'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException' was thrown.
```

Sometimes the exception is coming from SQS, the thing is when I was working with the version 6 I didn't have those exceptions.

This solution has three projects:

- Two web applications (which produce the messages)
- BackgroundService (which receive and process the messages)

I designed this system using CQRS pattern with several commands and for that reason it's creating 100 topics and I don't know if I need to consider some limits either from AWS or MassTransit

Someone can help me? Thanks

Comment: MassTransit is just a pass-through to SQS/SNS, so the rate limits are being enforced by Amazon. SNS is only used to publish messages, how many msg/s are you publishing?

Comment: These exceptions are happening when the BackgroundService is starting, so specifically when it calls IBusControl.Start and after a couple of seconds it throws the exception without sending or receiving any messages. When the background service is able to initialized it receives and sends messages without exceptions at all. Another thing I saw and it could be important, I checked the event history on CloudTrail from AWS after the exception and I saw a long list of calls between ListTopics and GetTopicAttributes. Thanks

Comment: So, perhaps permissions?

Comment: Not really because I created an api user with AdministratorAccess policy to work with this case. I was thinking in the way the topics are loaded one by one and try using the method ListTopicsAsync and then use the GetTopicAttributes by topic. What do you think?

Comment: No clue, that's all under the hood in the AWS client SDK.

Comment: I know that on TopicCache class the topics are loaded one by one (using FindTopicAsync), the idea I have that might help is to load all the topics using ListTopicsAsync so it doesn't need to make 100 requests for all the topics. What do you think?

Comment: Sure, that might be a nice option to avoid multiple calls (since the SDK is apparently coding really poorly).